# Uploading a file from .NET application to a Web API POST endpoint

Tags: asp.net, http, file-upload, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to use Web API to build some endpoints for applications to consume. The first job I'd like it to do is allow the client to upload a file to the server.

The client will run a .NET app of some kind, maybe a console app or maybe something else. It won't be a webpage using a form element or file input.

I think the Web API would look something like this:

```
public class FileController : ApiController
{
    public bool Post(File newFile)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Using this as a model class:

```
public class File
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Stream uploadStream { get; set; }
}
```

I'm sure that's horribly wrong but it's my first Web API.

I'm trying to test this in a console application:

```
namespace TestFileUpload
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting the test...");

            using (FileStream readstream = new FileStream(@"C:\\Test\Test2.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            WebAPI.Classes.File newFile = new WebAPI.Classes.File()
            {
                name = "Test.txt",
                uploadStream = readstream
            };

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50326");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response;
            response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:50326/api/file", newFile).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);

        };

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting a timeout error when I try to get the response:
"Error getting value from 'ReadTimeout' on 'System.IO.FileStream'."

Help?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for a client to consume a Web API service, but the most straight forward would be to use the web api client library.  Perhaps you should consider building a simple get method that returns an object before jumping into file uploads.

[Web API from .NET Client](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

You can not add a service reference as Web API does not expose a wsdl.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the updated question; I'm now using the advice you pointed me to but I'm not seeing any http request going out.

Comment: First, the base address looks wrong.  It should be just base, such as "http://localhost:50326".  Second, there must be an exception or the Result property should clue us into what is wrong.  What do they say?  Its hard to guess...

Comment: Updated the question. I'm getting an exception on the FileStream.